# How to find if a node exists in the binary tree or not (by index, not by value)?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Given a complete binary tree, in which the nodes are indexed from 1 to N (index 1 being the root, N is the number of nodes in a tree). Can we find if a node with a particular index exists in the tree or not, in O(logN) time complexity?

```
How is the indexing done?
for a node say it has      index x
                          /        \
             node.left is 2*x    node.right is 2*x+1
```

Below I have written the code that runs in O(N)

The O(N) solution seems highly inefficient when the node is somewhere deep down in right sub tree. Can we avoid visiting the left subtree at the root level?

Is it possible to achieve this objective in O(logN) time complexity by making use of the fact that it is a complete binary tree?

```
##TreeNode object
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

##findIndex
def findIndex(root,index,target):
    if root == None:
        return False
    if index == target:
        return True

    leftSide = findIndex(root.left,2*index,target)
    rightSide = findIndex(root.right,2*index+1,target)

    return (leftSide or rightSide)

##Create tree
root = TreeNode(1)
root.left = TreeNode(2)
root.right = TreeNode(3)
root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
root.left.right = TreeNode(5)

"""
For the sake of simplicity, 
the tree node values are the same as their index.
                1
               /  \
             2     3
            / \  
           4   5
"""

##call findIndex

## findIndex(root, startIndex, targetIndex) 

print findIndex(root,1,1) ## returns True
print findIndex(root,1,8) ## returns False
```

Comment: I' m still puzzled about how the index arranged in the tree.

Comment: for a node say it has index x, node.left is 2*x and node.right is 2*x+1

Comment: so by continuously dividing 2 you can calculate the path

Comment: @Constructor, can you elaborate on that idea? I tried to observe a pattern in the indexes of left and the right subtree I couldn't find anything of that sort.

Comment: e.g. index 11, by dividing 2 : 11 5 2 1

Comment: the reverse order is its path. It's obviously a O(logN) solution.

Comment: @Constructor your logic makes sense. Can you elaborate and put that up as an answer to this question?

Comment: OK, later I' ll post an answer, but I' m so busy at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we already know that the left node is 2*n and right node is 2*n + 1. Lets first start from the given index in the input and find out the path. 
For example, if we had index as 10 then we know that 10 should be to the left of 5, which in turn should be to the right of 2, which is to the left of root or 1.
So path is left, right, left. Now, just traverse this path in the Binary Tree as long as its null if the node exists return true else false.

Answer (score 2):

Use Stack:

1. divide by 2, since we know the index of each node is twice of its parent. if a parent is `i`, the left child is `2i` and the right child is  `2i+1`.
2. we have an index so we push its parents to reach root to stack.
3. remove from stack one by one and choose decision-based on odd and even being. finally, if that node exists it means the tree had that node.

```
 private boolean nodeExist(TreeNode node, int idx){
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        int temp = idx;
        while(temp !=1){
            stack.push(temp);
            temp /=2;
        }
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            if(stack.pop() %2 ==0){
                node = node.left;
            }else{
                node = node.right;
            }
        }
        
        return node !=null;
    }
```